Lorentz symmetry violation at Planck scales
Why is Lorentz invariance of a relativistic theory considered important?
I have come across a few articles (a sample) which assumes Lorentz symmetry violation at short distances, e.g., Planck scales.
Please explain this in a simpler language.
What is the plausibility of such a theory?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/809257
